# Enhance magnetic field for a levitating plant

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, levitation

## Problem

I bought a [levitating pot](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01JFBK8HO) and it looks great!

But I wonder if I can enhance the magnetic field somehow.

---

## Potential solution

I thought of wrapping the base (which produces the magnetic field) in a wooden structure (or a carved log) in which I will add some magnets or something to enhance the magnetic field.

Here is a sexy drawing :

[image: Drawing]

---

I was wondering if :

1. It is possible to enhance a magnetic field without altering the device.
2. My potential solution is ...a "potential solution".
3. There is a simpler or more realistic solution.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to increase the levitation height. That's probably not possible. Stable electromagnetic levitation is tricky to achieve, and your device probably already does the best that it can: if it could give you more height stably by using more powerful magnets, or by a minor tweak to the control circuitry, it would already do so.

Electromagnetic levitation devices contain sensors to detect the magnetic field (typically Hall effect sensors), and circuitry which respond to any changes in the field by modifying the current sent to the various electromagnets. To achieve a degree of stable levitation the response time must be fast. For example, the system analysed on [this page](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=electromagnetic-levitation) operates at a speed of 100,000 cycles per second. To achieve greater height, not only do the fixed magnets & electromagnets need to be stronger, the response time of the control system also needs to be faster, which means that you need to be able to increase the speed that the elecyromagnets' strength changes. And that may require using different materials for the electromagnets to overcome the time lag in changes to the magnetic field.

FWIW, there's lots of general info about magnets and magnetism, and links to various magnetic toys, on the [CoolMagnetMan site](http://www.coolmagnetman.com/magindex.htm).